# Difficulty with creating a rss feed

Tags: php, cakephp, rss, atom-feed

I have created a rss feed for my blog, it validates fine. I get this recommendation

```
line 1, column 1831: Missing atom:link with rel="self"
```

I have limited knowledge. How could I fix this I appreciate all help.

Thanks.

Comment: http://feed2.w3.org/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means pretty much what it says, that there's no link in your feed that points back to itself.  Not having such a link is still perfectly valid, but it's advantageous to have it for various reasons.  For example, should someone come across your feed being hosted on a third party site, they can use the self link to find the original source.

The Atom specs should have more information regarding what you need to do to correct this.